# In Odoo 15, I cannot manage active users due an error

Tags: python, odoo-15

Good Day
In Odoo 15, when I click on manage users, an error message prompt and asks me to copy the error code.
I also cannot add languages, edit them or manage them and I cannot edit companies or view them.
I need your kind help to resolve this issue

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 910, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1326, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1318, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 462, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 442, in _call_kw_model_create
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-99>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 391, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/res_config.py", line 784, in create
    return super(ResConfigSettings, self).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_fields.py", line 613, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4036, in create
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r on model %r" % (key, self._name))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Invalid field 'vat_check_vies' on model 'res.config.settings'```
````

Comment: You are probably missing a module that provides this field. Try searching through the source code and find the module and make sure it's installed

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. I just updated python3 on the ssh. I don't know how to search for the required module.

Comment: I believe the module is VAT Number Validation